# Can ZFS be used in 22.04?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, 22.04

have 4 drives, two M2 drives and two SSDs. I would like to take the 2nd M2 drive and the two SSDs and make them a ZFS pool. I **do not want to touch the book drive**, that stays ext4.

In 22.04 can I mix file system types? an I mix NVM and SDD in a ZFS pool? Is ZFS part of the kernel? Can a missed update cause a loss of data drives?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Short answer to the first three questions is “yes”. The short answer to the last question is “depends on how many updates, but not usually”. A long answer to these questions would take the better part of an hour to write 

Comment: Oh heavens, please do not write a hours worth! I think I am just going to create a simple pool with the 3-1TB drives and be done with it. Thanks for your response!